# JPQL Collection field Mapping it is possible?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, jdbc

I have a question, is it possible in Jpa to map collections of entity field to Dto?
Below is an example with List

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class MyEntity {
   private String name;
   @ManyToMany(...)
   private List<Projects> projects;

}
```

Dto:

```
public class MyEntityDto {
  private List<Projects> projects;
}
```

Query:

```
@Query(value="""
SELECT com.myprojects.myapp.dto.MyEntityDto (m.projects) FROM MyEntity m WHERE m.name=:someName
""")
MyEntityDto getByUniqueName(@Param("someName") name)
```

It didn't work in my project, so I wanted to ask as a question

Comment: Have you tried `List<MyEntityDto> getByUniqueName(@Param("someNamee") name)`

Comment: @Jens oh sorry not someNamee, it is someName. I edited

Comment: No, JPA will not return collections in queries. 'm.projects' is treated as a join to projects and so will give you individual projects one by one from the collection. You might be better off returning MyEntity to the DTO and letting it pull out the collection: "SELECT new MyEntityDto(m) FROM MyEntity m WHERE m.name=:someName"

Answer (score 0):

@Query(value="""
SELECT new com.myprojects.myapp.dto.MyEntityDto (m.projects) FROM MyEntity m WHERE m.name=:someName
""") and change return to List.
And use the all-args contructor in DTO . Try with this...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).